# Is $(X (X X)) ((X X) X) X$ the most simple representation of the identity combinator when $X = \lambda x . x KSK$?

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

Let combinator $X = \lambda x . x KSK$ as described by Hankin (1994).

Then $K = (X X) X$ and $S = X(X X)$.

Identity combinator however seems to have much more verbose form.

If $I = SKK$ then also $$I = (X(XX))((XX)X)((XX)X)$$

I could possibly make this a bit shorter:

$$I = (X (X X)) ((X X) X) X$$

but is this as far as you can get with representing $I$ with $X$ combinators?

I'm comparing $X$ with Baker (2001) Iota combinator $X' = \lambda x . x SK$, which seems to have dramatically less verbose counter part for $I = X'X'$ but on the other hand it takes extra $X'$ to define $S$ and $K$ compared to Hankin's.

Comment: Should we transfer this question to https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?